# making an input field inside of menu (li) responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu, and the last item contains a search input field. I would like the input field to be responsive, so that I can resize the window and avoid a menu line break at any cost.
I don't want to use media queries, since the menu will eventually be in a wordpress theme, so the items will be dynamic (different amounts of items, and different length of words). Of course at some stage the menu will break if there are too many items, but I would have still liked to find a solution to have a min-/max width for the input search field.

I am not sure if this is even possible. If not, are there any alternative solutions?

http://jsfiddle.net/aobrien/271vx59d/

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>Link 1</li>
        <li>Link 2</li>
        <li>Link 3</li>
        <li>Link 4</li>
        <li>Link 5</li>
        <li>Link 6</li>
        <li>Link 7</li>
        <li>Link 8</li>
        <li>Link 9</li>
        <li>Link 10</li>
        <li>
            <form method="get" class="search-form2" action="/" >
                <input type="search"placeholder="Search" />
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
.menu {
    color:#FFF;
    width:100%;
    background:#000;
}

.menu > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px 0;
    margin:0;
}
.menu > ul > li {
    list-style:inside none;
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid #FFF;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.menu > ul > li:last-child{
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right:none;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: It is. Just have a look at [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: It is not possible to fit all that in one line for small screens without it looking really bad and creating a poor user experience. Use something like this as an alternative. https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/
You can also use the customizer if you dont want all bootstrap code

Comment: @ Quentin Roy, media queries are not a solution,since the menu needs to stay dynamic, depending on how many items there are and how long the menu words are. Of course at some stage it will break if it's too long, but I would have liked to find an easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like the input field to be responsive, so that I can resize the window and avoid a menu line break ***at any cost***.

You can remove the `float` and use `display: table-cell` and `white-space: nowrap` on the `<li>` elements like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/271vx59d/7/

```css
.menu {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}
.menu > ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu > ul > li {
  list-style: inside none;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu > ul > li:last-child {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: none;
  text-align: right;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
    <li>Link 4</li>
    <li>Link 5</li>
    <li>Link 6</li>
    <li>Link 7</li>
    <li>Link 8</li>
    <li>Link 9</li>
    <li>Link 10</li>
    <li>
      <form method="get" class="search-form2" action="/">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks great, except for one part. I'd like to keep the search bar floated to the right. Adding `float:right` to last item seems to create a line break again. I can edit the html. Maybe wrapping the form inside of a div. I'll give it a try.

Comment: ok see updated answer.  you can use `display: table` on the `<ul>` and `text-align: right` on the last `<li>`

Comment: the snippet is too narrow too see but the input would take up all remaining space until it got to your max-width of 400px and then it would stay to the right.

Comment: The fiddle you linked to, works perfectly. Thank you so much.